# What do historians say would have been Napoleon's optimal strategy after Borodino?

Tags: russia, historiography, napoleonic-wars, napoleon

There is a saying that everyone is a general after the battle, but I still could not figure out what could have Napoleon done differently in order to save his army and consequently empire after Borodino. Historically, he stayed in Moscow some time, then tried to go to Smolensk (his supply base) via Kaluga, through countryside that was not devastated by previous marches and campaigns in order to obtain necessary forage and other supplies. But after [Maloyaroslavets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Maloyaroslavets), he abandoned that goal and went towards Smolensk roughly on the same road he took during advance on Moscow in previous summer. What would have been a better solution for him and his forces according to professional historians?

a) to retreat immediately after Borodino towards Smolensk, before the onset of winter

b) to stay in Moscow and try to prepare winter quarters there, then to resume campaign in spring

c) to push towards Kaluga no matter the cost even after Maloyaroslavets

d) something totally different

e) nothing would have saved him at that point

Comment: Perhaps the saying refers to the battle itself, and Napoleon's refusal to commit the Guard (or Kutuzov's poor placement of troops)? By the end of the Battle of Borodino, Napoleon's Grande Armee had already lost 3/4 of its strength. Napoleon could no longer counter Kutuzov's decision to not commit to another decisive battle.

Comment: This question will rapidly get closed as Opinion Based - but I believe he is toast once he advances past Smolensk. If he had started to partition Western Russia into new sovereign states, as he had done so successfully in Italy and with Duchy of Warsaw, he gains new allies and forces Alexander to attack French forces entrenched and well supplied.

Comment: @SPavel Trough, but Russians had also suffered terribly . Napoleon still had advantage in strength vs main body of Russians (Kutuzov)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I doubt he had a time and means for political games, after all most of Russian nobility and large part of clergy and merchant class fled before his advance .

Comment: @rs.29: Belorussians, Ukrainians, Lithuanians Latvians and Estonians are not Russians. Once the Russian clergy and nobles had departed, those regions were, I believe, ripe for independence. That puts Napoleon on the (winning) Nationalist side in 1813 instead of the (losing) Imperialist side. It further signals to his German Allies a commitment to their eventual independence.

Comment: Napoleon could still have saved his "empire" after Borodino and after the loss of his Grand Army in Russia, considering that he was "Emperor of the French" and not "Emperor of Europe".  Napoleon would have needed a mixture of superior diplomacy and superior war than he used in real life, to achieve a peace which left himself or his dynasty on the throne.  When Napoleon was reported killed in Russia, he was shocked to hear that nobody proclaimed his son his successor.  Continued.

Comment: Continued.  In our timeline Napoleon died in 1821 only 9 years after Russia, when his son was a lot older than in 1812 but still only 10.  So the Bonaparte dynasty was not firmly on the throne.  Napoleon would have needed to find someway to make his regime more appealing to the French and also more acceptable to the rulers of Europe (partially contradictory conditions) on the diplomatic front and won more battles post 1812 on the military front to keep himself and/or his family on (some of) their thrones.  That would have been difficult but not theoretically impossible.

Comment: @MAGolding: Nonsense - France had run out of men by then, which is why Napoleon had to conscript the "*Marie-Louise*"s, the classes of both 1814 and 1815, in October 1813. He was critically dependent on allied German forces to defend France, and when they deserted he was lost.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens  And I say that it was theoretically possible for Napoleon to make a deal for peace with his enemies before the battles in 1813.   He would have had to give up a lot to appease his enemies and that might have made the French discounted about the loss of glory, so that would have been a tough balancing act.  But if he had offered good enough terms and fought the battles he had to fight skillfully enough he could have made peace and kept his throne.  That would have been theoretically possible after 1812.

Comment: @MAGolding: And if manna had fallen from heaven in November 1812 the *Grande Armee* would have survived Russia. This is why we don't entertain hypothetical questions.

Comment: It's a nice question, but not for this forum. We look at history itself. We don't really do history-what-if scenarios.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Belorussians and Ukrainians considered themselves to be Russian back in 1812. Those nation were created at latter date. Even today Belorussians are very close to Russians. Baltic nations are tiny, and at that time they have been used to switching masters, so that would not change situation dramatically.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Btw, French were not in Ukraine in 1812, they did hold part of today's Belarus but not whole territory.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Two counterargument for that: A) the reason for the invasion of Russia was the Tzar breaking the embargo ("continental system") against England. Taking away a slice of Russia would not solve that. B) It would have needed a constant presence of the French Army at some thousands of kilometers away from home. Also, I do not understand the part about "commitment for the independence of the Germans". Typically, supporting the independence of your enemy subjects is not correlated with supporting the independence of YOUR subjects (see how Poland was treated).

Comment: @Jos: I made the question more objective by turning it into a "historiography" question. That question can be answered. I voted to reopen the question in its current form.